# Windows 10 fully transparent Start Menu

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I have looked for literally hours to find a way to make my Start Menu fully transparent but i was not able to find a way(everything I found online did not work).

Is anyone able to help me?

Comment: What you want probably require you to use third-party software since what you want is not possible out of the box on Windows 10.

Comment: Open-Shell-Menu, https://open-shell.github.io/Open-Shell-Menu/ , lets you specify menu opacity, taskbar opacity, "glass" look, etc.

Comment: Yeah but i want to keep my start menu (wich 3rd party software could i use)

Comment: Glass8 seems to do what you want: https://www.glass8.eu/

Comment: Looks like but I have 20h2 and glass8 chrashes all pc's over 2004 (any other ideas?)